How can I combine two square waves to make alternating current?
I was playing with a relay and tried to make square wave generator with it.

How can I improve this circuit and merge the two square waves to make alternating current?
The red color in the circuit is just showing the voltage.

think about other types of relays that you could use in your circuit ... for example, research how a relay can be used to control a DC motor bidirectionaly

@jsotola Thank you boss

You could use a double-pole, double-throw (DPDT) relay to create a (square wave) alternating current.


